# DB2 Internal failure occurred in query processor

Tags: db2, ibm-midrange, db2-400

We have two as400's  both V6R1M0 One is our Development and the other Production.

Please note I do not know the as400 that well.

I created a test webpage running from IIS to recreate the scenario.

The page has a button that creates a connection to db2 database and I do a select from a few tables with SQL and populate a grid with the data.

This works fine in DEV but when I run the same site but pointing it to our Production environment it fails with an error code SQL0901 SQL system error.

Note : I did check the SQL and the query itself is working in both environments.

On the green screen When I check The joblog of the page I get the following error:
[image]

Next I Checked google on the error and It seems like a PTF that needs to be installed in Production.(I do not know witch one). It has something to do with db2.

The problem that we have is that There are also other systems running on our Production environment and I am scared that when installing a PTF that it will cause issues...

How do I know what PTF to install by comparing DEV and Production? Is there software to do the comparing? Ideally I would only like to install the PTF that is in DEV but not in PRD.. Once again I dont know witch PTF will fix my issue.

Any help will be appreciated.

Added:

On the green screen when I press F1 on the error(QQQVECI: Did not find external field!!!.) I get the following:

[image]

When I then Press F9 to view details I get the following:

[image]

Comment: On that joblog page, can you hit position the cursor on the line that says "Did not find external field!!!" That message looks like the likely culprit and might give more details.

Comment: @TracyProbst I have added the messages that I get for that error.

Comment: Thanks, @Renier.  It looks like the answers below about applying PTFs are correct.  If PTFs applications are just out of the question, then it might be best to restructure your query altogether to work around it.  That can be difficult when we don't know the true root cause.  There is more than one PTF listed that may deal with this particular error.

Comment: In general you should always be current on PTF's for exactly this reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hard to be sure, but the general PTF you might be missing should be [**SI47445**](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=nas3c394319fe4d5d68586257a4b0068c2ed). Unfortunately, that was superseded a couple years ago by PTF SI47911. And that was later superseded by PTF SI50956. And each of those has pre-req and co-req PTFs.

As @Charles mentions, your admins will be closely involved. It's quite possible that nothing can be done for some time until some downtime can be scheduled for maintenance.

PTF SI47445 was part of **PTF cume package 2305**, a general collection of fixes available at the beginning of November 2012. At least one additional cume package was released for IBM i 6.1 in 2013, and some unknown number of individual PTFs since. The potential number of differences in PTFs between a system that is missing a cume package from as far back as 2012 and a more current system is possibly in the hundreds of PTFs.

Even your admins are likely to resist trying to figure the right way to get a single PTF applied.

A possible generally appropriate plan *would have been* to apply cume package 2305 on your DEV system in early January 2013. That would give a couple months for various early-adopter sites around the country (or world) to report problems with it and for IBM to correct them. Then, if DEV seemed okay, your PROD system could get the same cume package a month later, in early February 2013. (A few group PTF packages should go along with cume packages.)

But that plan is apparently moot.

Now, a more likely plan would involve (1) noting what cume and group packages are on DEV, and (2) determining if the media for each of those is still available to your admins for use on PROD.

If the media is no longer available, a somewhat different plan would need to be considered.

Answer (score 2):

You need to get your IBM i admins involved.

**Internal failure occurred in query processor** is certainly indicative of a bug in the OS that's needs to be/or has been corrected by IBM.

Your admins, possibly with IBM's help, can determine if there's an existing PTF to correct whatever is causing the error.

Your admins can then download and apply the PTF.

It is unlikely you would be able to download the PTF, let alone have the authority to apply it in production.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for you reply, could you also please look at the detail that I added.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with other answers about the likely PTF, but to answer your question

> How do I know what PTF to install by comparing DEV and Production? Is there software to do the comparing?

IBM recently enhanced the [IBM Application Runtime Expert](http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/power/software/i/are/) product to help with just this problem. The new PTF support in ARE is able to compare the system PTF levels against:

- Latest PTF group levels from [Preventative Service Planning](http://www-912.ibm.com/s_dir/sline003.nsf/GroupPTFs)
- PTF levels on a different system, eg. compare PROD to DEV
- Specified list of PTFs

In addition, it's able to automatically apply the missing PTFs on the target system if you want.

See this [blog](http://www.ibmsystemsmag.com/Blogs/i-Can/September-2015/IBM-Application-Runtime-Expert-for-i--Managing-PTF/) for more information on how to take advantage of the support.

Comment: It's not clear how ARE could identify the needed PTF. Example? ARE is a good way to help in maintaining consistency among systems, and doing more. OP should be aware that it's not so directly helpful in the current case where a specific unidentified PTF (an older one) may be needed without also attending to cume/group PTFs. But it's a good start for getting things current on DEV, and then PROD, apart from specifically "fixing" this problem. And it's quite possibly the way for OP's admins to go forward.

Comment: The example is in the blog I linked, but basically with the new PTF support ARE can compare the list of PTFs installed on one system A to system B (and C, D, E, ...)  identifying those that are installed on A but not on B and those on B not on A.

Comment: Yes, but how would it identify that SI47445 is the _needed PTF_? Identifying the list of differences is almost trivial just by comparing either WRKPTFGRP on the two systems or comparing outfiles from DSPPTF. Again, I support the use of ARE. Just wondering if it's particularly useful in this case.

Comment: I don't know that any tool could have told you that SI47445 is the needed PTF, but ARE will make it easier to see what the actual differences are so that you don't have to search through all the PTFs (your examples would work as well).

Regardless, in my opinion it doesn't really matter as your production environment should match your development environment (or staging/qa if you have one), so who cares which PTF it is? Just install all the PTFs that are missing.

Comment: Fully agreed there. A reasonably short staging/testing period, then get it done (especially before end-of-support).